# A question about The Generalized Minkowski Inequality

Tags: real-analysis

I got this from  F. Jones' Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space, Section 11.E, the author claims that:

$$
\begin{array}{l}{\text { Now let } 1<p<\infty \text { and define a new function } g \text { on } X \times Y \text { by the formula }} \\ {\qquad g(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}{f(x, y)\left\|f_{y}\right\|_{p}^{-1 / p^{\prime}}} & {\text { if } \quad 0<\left\|f_{y}\right\|_{p}<\infty} \\ {0} & {\text { if }\left\|f_{y}\right\|_{p}=0} \\ {\infty} & {\text { if }\left\|f_{y}\right\|_{p}=\infty}\end{array}\right.}\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{l}{\text { Of course, } p^{\prime} \text { is the Hölder conjugate of } p . \text { Then for each } y \in Y} \\ {\qquad f(x, y) \leq g(x, y)\left\|f_{y}\right\|_{p}^{1 / p^{\prime}} \quad \text { for } \mu \text { -a.e. } \quad x \in X}\end{array}
$$

Why is $
f(x, y) \leq g(x, y)\left\|f_{y}\right\|_{p}^{1 / p^{\prime}}
$?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the 3 cases. For any $y\in Y$, by definition of $g$,

- if $0 < \lVert f_y\rVert_p < \infty$, $f(x,y) = g(x,y)\lVert f_y\rVert_p^{1/p'}$
- if $\lVert f_y\rVert_p = 0$, $f(x,y) = 0$ $\mu$-a.e.; and therefore $f(x,y) = 0 = g(x,y)\lVert f_y\rVert_p^{1/p'}$
- if $\lVert f_y\rVert_p = \infty$, $f(x,y) < \infty = g(x,y)\lVert f_y\rVert_p^{1/p'}$

so the inequality holds in all three cases.

Comment: I think I'm just confused about the second case, could you add more detail on why $
\text { if }\left\|f_{y}\right\|_{p}=0, f(x, y)=0
$? Thanks!

Comment: @maskliesink The equality is $\mu$-a.e., I should have specified. It's because $\lVert \cdot \rVert_p$ is a norm: if the norm of $f_y$ is $0$, then $f_y$ is zero a.e. But $f_y(x)=f(x,y)$.

Comment: Just another question, why $
f_{y}(x)=f(x, y)
$?

Comment: @maskliesink Where is $fy$ defined? I assumed that is the definition, being the only natural one that seems to make sense in this context.

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!